# how to skip validation when adding custom domain in Azure app service

Tags: azure

when adding a custom domain to Azure app service,  the system always trying to validate your custom domain, but this is very annoying for my case.

i have a CDN service which i have put my www. sub domain on it, and the now i am going to move my website to azure app service

actually i have the website up running already on app service,  and the only thing i need to do is point the origin server address to app service in CDN setting

but, i need to set up a custom domain on app service for www.  otherwise it won't load. 
so the worst thing is, when i try to add the www record as custom domain, it validates if the record is really pointed to app service, which is definitely not possible because if i switch the domain really to app service,

1. first, i can not guarantee all user will get the dns change in same
   time
2. second, then i need to switch www back to CDN after the
   validation, then during this period, my app will work without cdn,
   which will be a problem also

so is there anyway to add a custom domain without validation.

this is really stupid, i have to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe i am stupid

found the way in office MS documents

here is the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-custom-domain-name-migrate

you can set up a txt verification recond to pass the verification